# Audio mixer - is ground isolation needed for each channel?

Tags: audio, ground, isolation

In every audio mixer schematic that I have found, the signal circuit is described extensively. Here are a few examples:

[image]

[image]

However, these diagrams do not show any considerations for the ground connections or isolation for the input's grounds. Is this required?  Can all of the grounds for all of the inputs be connected together without creating any signal contamination, or should there be some resistance (or other element) added?

Comment: Those signals you're mixing only exist as long as there is a ground connection. If you isolate the grounds, there will be no current flowing, and thus no signals.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually way more complicated (and painful) then it at first appears.

Firstly, the word 'Ground' sucks, try not to use it because it means about half a dozen different things in a subtle and highly context dependent way.

Secondly, both of those mixer circuits suck in different ways (Quite apart from the issues around 'grounding').

The fundamentals are that currents flow in loops, and voltages are developed between the ends of impedances in proportion the current flowing and the impedance.
This is something of a pain because it means that a common impedance of say 10mR shared between a 1mA output current and a mic input will develop 10uV due to that output current which will be  imposed on the mic input which has maybe 60dB of gain at which point you have 10mV of crosstalk, on maybe a 1V signal, so only 40dB down, which is a problem.

The old answer was something called 'star grounds' where all the grounds return individually to a single common point, it sort of works, kind of, as long as the frequency was always low enough to make resistance and not inductance important. This is no longer the case when we all carry microwave band radios in our pockets, and where low impedance design is routine to minimise Johnson noise.

The more way involves two things, firstly making all the IO balanced lines, so the external signal wiring has cable screens that terminate as directly as possible at the chassis (Never the internal signal reference), with the an internal 'refence voltage' net that carries little current and is connected to the chassis at ONE point (So that currents in the cable screens cannot flow in the refence net). See AES48 for the detail. There is generally a 'ground plane' on the board, but it connects to chassis at one point.

What I personally consider to be the state of the art is using a 'ground plane' and making all the signal processing stages inverting and set up to measure between two points and to drive the output relative to a defined point (Ground sensing), then a net tie to the ground plane at a single point between stages makes the doings insensitive to noise on the ground plane. It is amazing to build a low noise audio thing and then deliberately pump AMPS of noise current thru the ground plane and have the thing remain totally silent.

Bruno Putzeys is the guy who came up with this and advocates for it in the following paper : https://www.diyaudio.com/community/attachments/wp_the_g_word-pdf.886214/

The current return path is the OTHER half of the schematic, it is that critical in low noise audio doings.

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, the mixer usually functions as the central grounding tie point for the entire system.

For the inputs in particular, which are mostly connected to microphones that have no other ground reference, this is particularly important.

Only in special cases, such as taking an input from a separately-powered instrument amplifier, would you consider using a transformer or other form of isolation (i.e., a "direct box") to separate the grounds.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what keeps the signals from interfering with each other threw the ground connection?

Comment: Mainly through the use of balanced connections; e.g., TRS 1/4" plugs or 3-pin XLR connectors. This prevents signal currents from flowing in the ground connections at all, which is just used for electrostatic shielding. But even with unbalanced connections, the impedance of the individual ground connections to each of the inputs at the mixer should be low enough to prevent any kind of crosstalk.

Comment: There is no need for isolation in such low current circuits. There will be no significant current flow in those ground points to the extend where it will offset the zero voltage in any of the ground node. Isolation or star grounding will be needed only under such circumstances.